# Can we update the icon in iPhone SDK 3.0 like the calendar app does?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

On the iPhone and iPod Touch the calendar application changes the icon ever day so that it displays today's date. I have used a support incident with Apple to figure out how to do this in 2.x but they say you cannot.

Has anyone found an API in the new iPhone 3.0 SDK that allows this?

Comment: Isn't the 3.0 SDK under an NDA?

Comment: I want to change the change my icon like the calendar app does. I do NOT want to display a date.

Comment: Yes, the 3.0 SDK is under NDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't appear so:

> You can not change anything in your app bundle and that includes the icon, using the SDK.

Although a couple of people have some possible hackie ideas.

http://collison.ie/blog/2008/11/dynamic-defaultpng-files-on-the-iphone

**Sources**

https://devforums.apple.com/message/36001

https://devforums.apple.com/message/34548